# absolute Div keeps on flickering if i move my mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what i have achieved so far:

[image]

A `div` will appear on the pointer of my mouse if i will move my mouse anywhere red image.

Here are my codes:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test" class="cclass" style="border:solid">
name:blahblah <br />
name:blahblah <br />
name:blahblah <br />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cclass {
position:absolute;
background-color:orange;
height:125px;
width:175px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
display:none;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('img#sorc').on('mousemove mouseleave',function (e) {


     if (e.type == 'mouseleave'){
     $('div#test').css('display', 'none');

     }                

     else {

     $('div#test').css({

           'display': 'block',
           'top': e.pageY,
           'left': e.pageX

           });
         }
});
```

It works as intended but the problem is that, the div keeps on flickering. What should i do to avoid that?

edit:

this is code for my red box:

```
<img id="sorc" src="~/photos/test.jpg" />
```

Comment: is this code reproducing your problem?

Comment: no but i am not sure if it's because of my approach. My code works but the `div` keeps on flickering instead of it displaying steadily.

Comment: where is red box in your code ?

Comment: Can you post fiddle?

Comment: Updated. it's just a plain img tag.

Comment: Just ensure adding `position: relative;` to your parent div or div with red color. An 'absolute' div without `relative` position to its parent will behave awkwardly.

Comment: your code is incomplete what is the matter if you hover or mousepoint on image than the orange box will appear or what ?

Comment: yes it will appear(the orange div) to anywhere i am pointing to. the `div` will follow my mouse pointer anywhere inside the red image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing a little gap between the cursor and the box-position resolves the issue. In the snippet below, I've set a `15px` gap on the X-axis.

```js
$('img#sorc').on('mousemove mouseleave', function(e) {
  if (e.type == 'mouseleave') {
    $('div#test').css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    $('div#test').css({
      'display': 'block',
      'top': e.pageY,
      'left': e.pageX + 15
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.cclass {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 125px;
  width: 175px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="sorc" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
<div id="test" class="cclass" style="border:solid">
  name:blahblah
  <br />name:blahblah
  <br />name:blahblah
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Eh that was weird though, so the only difference is adding 15px?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta You can add _any_ margin. I put `15px` because my cursor is about that wide, and allows me to see the whole box on hover.

Answer (score 1):

Created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58qkn7j7/2/) for you problem

modified your HTML code a bit. added one parent and given position as relative to that parent.

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <img id="sorc" src="~/photos/test.jpg" />
    <div id="test" class="cclass" style="border:solid">name:blahblah
        <br />name:blahblah
        <br />name:blahblah
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta Welcome mate!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing is your mouse is interfering with your blaah image, add sufficient margin to your cursor position, e.pageY + 10 , e.pageX + 10, or as mentioned in one of the answers make your container relative

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('img#sorc').on('mousemove mouseleave', function(e) {


  if (e.type == 'mouseleave') {
    $('div#test').css('display', 'none');

  } else {

    $('div#test').css({

      'display': 'block',
      'top': e.pageY,
      'left': e.pageX

    });
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.cclass {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 125px;
  width: 175px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <img id="sorc" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png " />
  <div id="test" class="cclass" style="border:solid">
    name:blahblah
    <br />name:blahblah
    <br />name:blahblah
    <br />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this one:

```
$('#sorc').on('mousemove mouseleave',function (e) {


     if (e.type == 'mouseleave'){
     $('div#test').css('display', 'none');

     }                

     else {

     $('div#test').css({

           'display': 'block',
           'top': e.pageY,
           'left': e.pageX

           });
         }
});
```

here my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/58qkn7j7/4/)