# Hover doesn't get triggered with mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is with regards to my previous question:
[absolute Div keeps on flickering if i move my mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775518/absolute-div-keeps-on-flickering-if-i-move-my-mouse)

I solved my problem by adding few distance between my mouse pointer and the div so i will keep that solution for now.

i am on the next phase of my implementation:

What i want to happen is to do a `$.ajax` call from the server the set the div's html depending on it's value/content(?) of the image **once** the mouse entered the `img`.

This is my initial attempt:

```
var $divt = $('div#test')
$('img#sorc').on({
    hover: function (e) {
        alert('enter'); //wont work
    },
    mousemove: function (e) {
        $divt.css({
            'display': 'block',
                'top': e.pageY,
                'left': e.pageX + 15
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $divt.css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

i decided to use `hover` so that the ajax call will only happen once the user's mouse entered the `img` but i didn't get that result and the alert box is not even triggering. I can do something like preload the div with the data from the server but i want to make my code dynamic and reusable so i am refraining from hardcoding anything. I only want to execute the ajax call once and not everytime the user moves the mouse around the image. How can i achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the ".on(<event>, function())" style of jQuery event handler not work for "hover"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791289/why-does-the-onevent-function-style-of-jquery-event-handler-not-work-f)

Comment: I just answered this 25 minutes ago.

Comment: So if i can't use hover then what are my alternatives? I want to execute the ajax call only once.

Comment: Use `mousenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: Oh alright, haven't thought of that. thank you

Comment: `hover` is just a shorthand for defining handlers for enter and leave with one call.

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is when mousein do a $.ajax and measure the x,y in box,when mouseout do a css change and doesn't measure x,y anymore.this may help:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <img id="sorc" src="./1.jpg" alt="">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $("img#sorc").hover(function() {
   alert("in") ;
   $("img#sorc").mousemove(function(e) {
    console.log(e.pageX) ;
    console.log(e.pageY) ;
   });
  }, function() {
   alert("out") ;
   $("img#sorc").unbind(onmousemove) ;
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```